# ruby on rails send value through redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

```
    @id =params[:ad]
   @empreasset = params[:check_box_id]
    case params[:commit]
    when 'delete'
      @empreasset.each do |empreasset|
        @em = Empreasset.find(empreasset)
        @em.destroy
  end
  @size=@empreasset.size
  @message = "#{@size} Employee asset(s) deleted sucessfully"
  respond_to do |format|

      format.html {redirect_to :action => :index, :id => @empreasset.ad}
      format.json {head :no_content}

end
```

Here (@empreasset.ad=@id) Also logic can be format.html {redirect_to :action => :index,   :id => @id}
    It is also ok. But error occurs..
     In controller index i have to send value of  id. As @empreasset.ad has same value for all data. I need to send one @empreasset.ad value. But how can it be possible since @empreasset.ad is in array. How can i pick only one value of @empreasset.ad and send in

redirect :id => @empreasset.ad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write one more line .  empreasset=@empreasset.first

then

format.html {redirect_to :action => :index, :id => empreasset.ad}

Answer (score 1):

@empreasset is an array, right?
To send one value of this array, use @empreasset.first.ad
This will get the property ad of the first element of the array.

Comment: then use a variable in the line above and pass to the id.